# Possible to save commands in variables?

Tags: variables, command, autohotkey

My idea was to a command like "Sleep, 2000" in a variable or even several commands. 
In this example you would type in the hotstring, then the program would wait 2 seconds and then the message box would pop up and tell you that you've slept for 2 seconds. 
However, I'm getting an error message for the line with "SleepVar1": "This line doesn't contain a recognized action"

```
SleepVar1 = Sleep, 2000

:*:svar::
SleepVar1 
msgbox, You slept 2 seconds
return
```

There must be a way to achieve this, right? Maybe not with variable but something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the names suggest:

- **Commands** are orders, tasks given to the OS.
- A **variable** is a placeholder for a value. The value can change, nevertheless a variable can only hold one value at a time.

To return a given value of a variable within commands, you need to enclose the variable in 
percent signs

```
SleepVar1 = 2000

:*:svar1::
    Sleep, %SleepVar1% 
    msgbox, You slept 2 seconds
return
```

or a [function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm):

```
; :X*:svar2::SleepVar(3000)

; or

:*:svar2::
    SleepVar(3000)
return

SleepVar(value){
    Sleep, %value%
    msgbox, You slept %value% miliseconds
}
```